# "Assume that A = B" subjunctive?

Tags: subjunctive-mood

[Over on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/447697/31475), a question exists regarding the usage of the word "that" in the following sentences:

1. Assume that A = B.
2. Assume A = B.

A well-known author suggests that users elect Option 1 in mathematical writing.

A discussion arose whether or not Option 1 is perfectly acceptable usage of the subjunctive, with a caveat: that the glyph "=" be read "equal" and not "equals."

The author of the book in question also further suggested that the word "that" be used only if it helps parse a sentence, "Assume **that** A is a group" vs. "Assume A is a group." This point was less contended, but in the subjunctive discussion, contrary concerns also arose whether the usage "Assume A be a group" is correct archaically, is correct presently, or has never been correct at all.

**First question:** given that "Assume..." is functionally equivalent to necessity in mathematical writing, is the sentence "Assume that A equal B" a proper use of the subjunctive?

**Second question:** Is, or has ever been, the usage "Assume that A be a group" been proper conjugation of "is" in a properly-used subjunctive?

**Third question:** Is there anything structurally unsavory about the use of the conjunction "that" in the form "Assume that A equals B" (note the s)?

Comment: The actual passage by Donald Knuth, the author in question, can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/447697/12042). This does not represent the ensuing discussion very accurately; unfortunately, most of that discussion is in the comments following a deleted answer and is therefore not likely to be visible to many people here.

Comment: Oops, you're right, I switched the options when I typed them; I'll fix that. Nevertheless, that doesn't change my question at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Patterning of the subjunctive is becoming very spotty in English, but is generally restricted to subordinate clauses licensed by verbs of compulsion or persuasion. e.g., *The court **orders/requests/requires/prays** that Thomas present himself for sentencing...* [pray used in its legal sense]. In modern American English (I don't know about older English) the preceding sentence doesn't work with psych verbs like **hope/wish/pray** [pray used in its common sense] or cognition verbs like **think/assume/believe/suppose**. Note also that the modal use of **were** (e.g., *Assume that Thomas were guilty...*) is usually called irrealis, not subjunctive.
2. That is correct, but only because **let** licenses a complement clause with its verb in the base form. It doesn't have to do with the subjunctive. (e.g., *The judge let Thomas delay the hearing...* is clearly not showing subjunctive mood)
3. Nothing structurally unsavory, and I agree that the best guideline on omitting or using **that** is to improve parseability.

Comment: Question two should instead read: "Assume that A be a group..." Would this still be correct?

Comment: @Arkamis It doesn't sound correct to me, no.

Answer (score 4):

Your “well-known author” doesn’t seem to know English very well.

The verb *assume* always takes the indicative in contemporary English.  The correct formulation is:

> I assume that he is coming.

And therefore, of

> Assume that A is equal to B.

or likewise

> Assume that A equals B.

You can find people who might say

> Suppose it were otherwise; what would you do?
>
> Imagine that it were different; what would you do?

But there aren’t many of those.

As for your second question,

> Let A be a group.

Is perfectly grammatical.

Finally, on your last question, there is nothing whatsoever wrong with having a *that* there, any more than there is anything wrong with not having it there.

---

### Edit

I suppose it might be possible that your writer is using *assume* as a substitute for *let*, making it a sort of auxiliary. It would therefore take a bare infinitive under that reading.

However, the OED presents no documented evidence of that sort of thing. The only thing of apparent relevance which the OED gives is this:

> **10**. *trans.* To take for granted as the basis of argument or action; to suppose: **a.** *that* a thing is, a thing *to be*.
>
> - 1841 Myers *Cath. Th.* iii. §25. 91 — To assume that we have the most accurate possible translation.
> - 1868 Peard *Water-farm.* x. 103 — The entire length of our farm is assumed to be about thirty-two miles.

There you have documentation that it takes both *that* and a simple indicative *is* form: *one assumes **that** a thing **is** such and such*.

Comment: I had swapped the order I wrote the options from the original post; the "well-known author" did get it right, I just wrote them in the wrong order without noticing :)

Comment: So, is "Assume it were otherwise; what would you do?" then an incorrect usage? What about "Require that it be otherwise."?

Comment: @Arkamis Both of your examples are permissible, but stuffy.

Comment: In the US, the percentage of people who would use the past indicative after verbs of supposition is quite small; in the UK it is somewhat higher. To me, “Suppose it was otherwise” sounds completely and utterly wrong. Note, however, that there is a big difference between past and present subjunctive in modern English, the latter being much rarer than the former. “Suppose it is” (indicative), but “Suppose it were”.

Comment: @tchrist: Do I understand correctly that you consider *be* in *In order to avoid technicalities, we require that the set A be non-empty* to be stuffy? I ask because in my idiolect it’s required. If I remember correctly, this is more common in the U.S. than in the U.K.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott No, I talk that way, too. Most people don’t.

Answer (score 2):

All right, the English subjunctive mood is tricky mostly because, in modern English, it's considered in many areas to be moribund or outmoded.  In most situations, the indicative and subjunctive can live side by side and have, in fact, done so since Middle English times.  I went to school for English and many of my theses have been written on this topic.  I shall break down the subjunctive, which can have a very formal, sometimes archaic feel to it, but is still quite beautiful, to say the least.  Here are some examples in the subjunctive mood (some examples may have a modal that replaces the subjunctive forms):

1. Assuming that he *be* correct, can we still get to the show in time?
2. "And ne'er throughout the year to church thou go'st/Except it *be* to pray against thy foes" (Shakespeare).
3. I pray that God *give* them the serenity that they *may forgive* this man.
4. O that I *were* the President of the United States.  What policies I would invoke *were* I holding that office.
5. I can only hope that he *find* true love one day.  It's my only hope and wish that he *be* as lucky as I have been in my lifetime with my wife.
6. *Should* he *violate* the terms of his parole, he shall be returned to prison forthwith.
7. Whether the committee *sanction* him or not, he will still remain in his tenured position on the board.
8. It is important that the students *do* their own work.
9. I demanded that they not *say* another word.
10. Though he *face* many perils, he will ultimately succeed. (Also, though he *may face* many perils...).
11. It's better if he *go* with you.
12. If you *had gone* to school, you would have had to take a test.
13. I wish I *were* an Oscar Meyer wiener.
14. If only he *knew* the answer, he wouldn't be in this predicament.
15. It is the judgment of this court that you *be sentenced* to probation.
16. He will be permitted to attend the ceremony provided he *dress* accordingly.
17. We shall do it on the condition that we *be paid* $5,000.
18. In the event that he *died* right now, his estate would devise to his next of kin.
19. As long as he *have answered* all of the questions, the chances of his failing are slim.
20. They will plant trees along the street in memory of the victims so that no one ever *forget* them.
21. If he *go* to the store, he will buy some eggs.
22. If I *were to go* with you, I would never forgive myself.
23. He fled the country lest he *be captured* and *imprisoned*.

The above examples are all correct under the rules of English grammar; however, many of them would be considered archaic if they were used today.  Despite their being overly formal or archaic, they limn the usage of the subjunctive in English in a diachronic analysis more so than just capturing its modern usage.  None of the 23 examples above could be deemed ungrammatical, but many people might categorize them as *stilted* nonetheless.  These examples were not shown to be stilted; they were shown so that readers could see the entire usage of the subjunctive.

The subjunctive can be used after many other coordinating conjunctions like "until", "unless", "although", and "before".  It can also be used after subordinating "that" clauses when those clauses are linked by words of necessity, possibility, contingency, commands, requests, aspirations, supplications, doubts, fears, and other operative words that evoke latent emotions that do not necessarily *indicate* that an event happens, will happen, or has happened.  Those words that would indicate such actual events would fall into the *indicative* mood, which is the common mood of language: "He *is* the one. I *went* to the store yesterday.  They *will find* the time to do it."

That is the English subjunctive mood in a nutshell.  One example I did not discuss, "Let there *be* light", is called the hortatory subjunctive so those above who proclaimed that "let" doesn't open up a subjunctive are wrong.